# WebSocket em localhost não estabelece conexão

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

Estou testando `WebSocket` rodando na porta `80`, ja desabilitei o *SSL*, mas não estou tendo resultados...

<sub>**javascript**</sub>

```
 var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:80/socket2.php');
```

Um exemplo que vi, testei e retorna com sucesso foi usando `wss://echo.websocket.org`. Então imagino que o o erro esteja por aqui mesmo. 
O retorno do navegador é sempre o mesmo:

> O Firefox não conseguiu estabelecer uma conexão com o servidor ws://localhost/socket2.php

---

Os headers como no [exemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers):

<sub>**socket2.php**</sub>

```
header("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols");

header("Upgrade: websocket");
header("Connection: Upgrade");
header("Sec-WebSocket-Accept: s3pPLMBiTxaQ9kYGzzhZRbK+xOo=");
```

---

No console a requisição do WebSocket retorna 101 / websocket / 0B

OBS: Uso **Apache**, esta tudo como antes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Socket é uma requisição que fica sempre aberta. É preciso uma aplicação sendo executada do outro lado. PHP é uma aplicação que tem "início-meio-fim". Pelo que você mostrou você está tentando conectar no socket fazendo uma chamada pro PHP, que está instruído a fazer exatamente: Enviar cabeçalhos e encerrar.

Recomendo fortemente não utilizar PHP no servidor para sockets. PHP não foi feito para isto. Para este problema em específico Node te traria maior desempenho e menor consumo de recursos.

Answer (score 2):

O servidor tem que ficar em uma porta diferente do apache, por padrão ela vem na 80, se seu apache está na 80, altere a porta do servidor para outra, 8080 por exemplo para que não haja conflito, acho que isso deve funcionar.